# Rewriting data in multiple files Java

Tags: java, file

After much reasearch is came up with the code that would re-write data in a file using regular expression however I am stomped on how to re-modify my code so that is reads the data in a directory filled with text files looks for the regex pattern and replaces it with the text i want. I am new at doing this any help would be appreciated this is what i have so far that work on a per file basis.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\hoflerj\\Desktop\\After\\test.txt");
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
content = content.replaceAll("2018(.+)", "XXXX");
Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));
```

I created some code a couple of months ago that reads filename and looks for a pattern and cuts the name length down it seems like i should do something similar but i cant quite put it together. That code is below.

```
for (File file:filesInDir) {
    //x++;
    String name = file.getName();
    String newName = name;
    //String sameName = name;
    if (name.contains("LABEL")){
        newName = name.replaceAll("\\-2018(.+)\\d", "") ; 
        System.out.println(newName); // prints prints to file 
        String newPath = absolutePathOne + "\\" + newName;
        file.renameTo(new File(newPath));
        //Files.move(file.toPath(), Paths.get(newPath)); 
    }
    if (!name.contains("LABEL")){
        newName = name.replaceAll("\\-2018(.+)", ""); 
        System.out.println(newName); // prints prints to file 
        String newPath = absolutePathOne + "\\" + newName +".txt";
        file.renameTo(new File(newPath));
        //Files.move(file.toPath(), Paths.get(newPath)); 
     }
}
```

Please help me connect the dots. Again my goal is to loop through all the files in the directory and find the pattern and replace the pattern with my preferred text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 7 Files API has many useful methods to achieve your goal. For example, there is the [Files.walk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) method that allows you to iterate over all files in the folder. To read, write and rename a file there are [Files.readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-), [Files.write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) and [Files.move](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) methods respectively.

So you could try something like this:

```
String folderPath = "/your/path";
String contentRegexp = "2018(.+)";
String contentReplacement = "XXXX";
String filenameRegexp = "-2018(.+)\\d";
String filenameReplacement = "";

// 1 is a maximum depth of traversal; 
// you can use it if you have any subdirectories wich you want to process too
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(folderPath), 1)) {
    // filtering only files
    paths.filter(file -> Files.isRegularFile(file))
         .forEach(file -> {
                try {
                    //reading all lines and replacing content in each line
                    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file)
                        .stream()
                        .map(s -> s.replaceAll(contentRegexp, contentReplacement))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    //writing lines back
                    Files.write(file, lines, StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
                                             StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
                    //renaming file
                    Files.move(file, file.resolveSibling(file.getFileName()
                                   .toString()
                                   .replaceAll(filenameRegexp, filenameReplacement)));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
          });
}
```

But be careful here with your regex: `2018(.+)` will replace '2018' **and everything after it in the string** with 'XXXX'.

Comment: Thanks I will try thus! :)

Comment: Question what if I don't want a file name filter can it work without? I don't care what the file name is i want it to do it regardless of the file name.

Comment: @Jonathan Of course it will work, you only need to remove `&& file.getFileName().toString().contains(fileNameFilter)` from the filtering condition

Comment: Question is there anyway to limit the contentRegexp to only the first occurrence? I looked into this with my regex online tool and this is as close as i can come up with 2018([^"]*).*\d

Comment: @JonathanHofler how does your actual string look like and what part of it do you want to replace?

Comment: 3-MAAAA2018/2/00346 to  3-MAAAAXXXX which works fine. However as you stated everything with 2018 and back -> will be x'ed out. I wanted to know of there is a way to control how many times it replaces the match.

Comment: @Jonathan If this is the exact format and you know for sure the number of digits after the second slash, you could use this regexp: `"2018/\\d+/\\d{5}"`. Here 5 is a number of digits after the second slash. If this number is unknown, but digits are followed by characters which you want to leave, then use `"2018/\\d+/\\d+"`

Comment: question what if I want to read the files from this file path and them write them to another file I  a file path? What woukd be the modification to the code above to have that Done?